# How do I hard code invalid chars in a string in VS

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding, char, encode

There is this environment I'm working on which only allows some very limited namespaces. I've came up with an encoding struct which encodes a file into a single hard coded string, and then I can load the string as a file during the runtime.

After I refined the struct to utilize the char type as an unsigned 16 bit, I encountered a problem that not all chars can be displayed and hard coded into a string; or sometimes a generated string is shortened when cast back. Is there any way I can approach this with a better method?

Comment: Consider embed whole file as **resource**?

Comment: @LeiYang Not supported.

Comment: Not support WHAT?

Comment: I use VS to build the solution, and then paste the code to the VSless environment. @LeiYang